# d[digits++] = digits;と書くと、インクリメントは式が終わったあとって聞いたんですけど、なってないみたいです。誰か説明してくれませんか。

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int end = 0;
    char d[5];
    int digits = 0;
    d[digits++] = digits;
    printf("digits=%d\n",digits);
    printf("d[0]=%d\n",d[0]);

    do{
        printf("if enter 1, end.");
        scanf("%d",&end);
    }while (end = 0);

    return 0;
}
```

---実行結果---
digits=1
d[0]=1
if enter 1, end.

---僕の理想の実行結果---
digits=1
d[0]=0　←ここが0
if enter 1, end.

Comment: `do-while`の条件式ですが、`end = 0`だと**代入**になってしまいますし、"1が入力されるまでループを続ける"としたいなら`while (end != 1)`の様な気がします。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: ちなみに、gcc version 8.2.0 で `-Wsequence-point` オプションを付けてコンパイルすると、`warning: operation on ‘digits’ may be undefined` と表示されます。

Comment: この質問は解決しましたか？解決した場合は参考になった回答を承認してください。承認は回答横のチェックマークを選択することで行えます。また解決していない場合は、不明点を質問に追記してください。質問の修正は`編集`ボタンから行えます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

式が終わった後にインクリメントされてるから`d[0]`に`1`が入ってるんですよ。

インクリメントは値を返した後に行われます。
つまり、`digits`の値を`d[digits++]`に使った後には加算済み。
なので、左辺の処理が終わった後には`digits`は加算済みで、その後右辺が処理され、代入処理がうごいていると思われます。

ただ、この左辺と右辺の演算順は定義されていなかったんじゃないかな？
なのでビルド環境を変えると、右辺処理して、左辺処理して、インクリメント、代入と所望の動きが得られるものもあるんじゃないかと思います。

Cでは定義されていない仕様もあって、その場合の結果は処理系に依存してしまいます。
要は、コンパイラなどのバイナリを出力する過程で使われるプログラムによって、出力結果が変わってしまう事があるということですね。
関数の定義などを見ていても、`～の場合は未定義`と説明されているのを見かけた事があるんじゃないでしょうか？

どのビルド環境だとそうなるという解は持ち合わせていませんが、処理系に依存するプログラムを書いていると、移植などを行う際に想定外の挙動が起きたりするのでオススメ出来ません。

Comment: すごくよくわかりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 9):

[EXP30-C. 副作用が発生する式の評価順序に依存しない](https://www.jpcert.or.jp/sc-rules/c-exp30-c.html)が参考になるでしょうか。

> ```
> d[digits++] = digits;
> ```

C言語では、演算子の結合順序は定められていますが、評価順序は一部を除いて定められていません。`=`の左右どちらを先に評価するかは未定義です。

#### 左辺値を先に評価した場合

`d[digits++]`が評価されます。`d[0]`を得つつ`digits`が`1`にインクリメントされます。次に`digits`が評価されます。`digits`は`1`です。最後に`=`が評価され`d[0]`は`1`となります。

#### 右辺値を先に評価した場合

`digits`が評価されます。`digits`は`0`です。次に`d[digits++]`が評価されます。`d[0]`を得つつ`digits`が`1`にインクリメントされます。最後に`=`が評価され`d[0]`は`0`となります。

---

「一部を除いて」とは、よく知られているように`&&`や`||`、`,`は左辺値を先に評価することが定められていますし、`?:`も条件式が先に評価されます。

Comment: すごくよくわかりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 厳密にいうとこの例は jpcert の例でいう未定義動作のほうなのですけど、それを説明しだすと長くなるし大変ですよね。